# How to replace characters in string with values from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var b = ['two', 'three', 'four'];
var string = 'The only one and two and three';
```

I tried to use for-loop.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    string = string.replace(a[0], b[0]);
    string = string.replace(a[1], b[1]);
    string = string.replace(a[2], b[2]);
}
```

But the problem is that after first iteration replaced value replaces again! I want to replace `one` with *two*, `two` with *three* and `three` with *four*.

Expected result: `The only two and three and four`

I get: `The only four and four and four`

Comment: It's a tricky question, but why do you iterate till `i < string.length`? I think, It should be `a.length` or `b.length`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var dict = {};
a.forEach(function(el, i) {
    dict[el] = b[i];
});

var patt = a.join('|');
var res = string.replace(new RegExp(patt, 'g'), function(word) {
    return dict[word];
});
console.log(res); // The only two and three and four
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwEum/). It's really simple actually: first you create a dictionary (where keys are words to be replaced, and values are, well, words to replace them), second, you create an 'alternation' regex (with `|` symbol - you'll need to quote metacharacters if there are any). Finally, you go through the string with a single `replace` using this created pattern - and a replacement function, that looks for a particular 'correction word' in the dictionary.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to reorder the replacements so that the ones in the 'corrections' list will go first. But that way is shaky - cross-references will break it right away.

Comment: As for `a.join` - actually I heard that creating an alternation from a list of words to look for is considered an optimization technique. )

Comment: Just posted an alternate approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/20478025/297641 not sure if I missed anything :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop, just replace backwards:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var b = ['two', 'three', 'four'];
var string = 'The only one and two and three';

string = string.replace(a[2], b[2]);
string = string.replace(a[1], b[1]);
string = string.replace(a[0], b[0]);
```

Note: this works for this example, it's not generic.

Comment: Not a generic answer, it relies on data. I think what he posted here is an example of his real issue.

Comment: @Vega The answer states that explicitly.

Comment: +1 Not sure how I missed it, but at least you had it as a note.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting an alternate approach which splits the original string and replace it from dict object.

The dict object is built before the replace as it is essential to know what is being replaced.

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var b = ['two', 'three', 'four'];
var string = 'The only one and two and three';

var dict = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    dict[a[i]] = b[i];
}

var stringtokens = string.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < stringtokens.length; i++) {
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(stringtokens[i])){
        stringtokens[i] = dict[stringtokens[i]];
    }
}

console.log(stringtokens.join(' '));
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4a2q/)**

Comment: OH, I'm sorry! You did exactly what I did and answered, I'll just delete it.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!It's the best way, no need to count string lengths or worry about keeping track of what's changed and what's not..

Comment: But what if there are no spaces in input string? I pasted in question simplified code, but in my script I need to replace characters that aren't splited by space. Sure, this is interesting solution, but not in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Do it backwards:

```
var a = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var b = ['two', 'three', 'four'];
var string = 'The only one and two and three';

for (var i = string.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    string = string.replace(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLmzj/)

Comment: Seems like your initial `i` should be `string.length - 1` to keep it in bounds. No harm here, but technically should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You may reverse every array to achieve this.
Another way is regular pattern.

Also, your code makes no sense. Why you iterating through string, if you need to iterate through arrays?

This would work:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    string = string.replace(a[a.length - 1 - i], b[b.length - 1 - i]);
}
```

Also, look at this universal way:
http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace/

You may do  so:

```
str_replace(['{name}', 'l'], ['hello', 'm'], '{name}, lars');
```

This function can get arrays as parameters.

Comment: I think it should be `a[a.length - 1 - i], b[b.length - 1 - i]`

Answer (score 0):

Just do it the other way around. The problem is that after you replace `one` with `two`, you replace all `two` with `three`, and then you do the same thing with `three` and `four`, leaving you will all `four` at the end. If you reverse the order of your replaces, that won't happen.